# If you have a default gateway in a different network to your current network, how can you configure the networking to use that other gateway?

Tags: networking

Could anyone answer the following question? 
If you have a default gateway in a different network to your current network, how can you configure the networking to use that other gateway? 
Thank you.

Comment: Can you leave your house through your neighbor's door?

Comment: You can't configure it this way.

Comment: This can't really be answered in the abstract. Please describe the network topology and include the specific device or operating system which you'd be configuring.

Answer (score 3):

You can't. You must configure a router that routes all traffic into the other network (and out of it via the gateway of that network) and use this router as the default gateway.

As an aside: Technically, it *might* be possible to define the remote gateway as the default and then add a route to this via the aforementioned router, but even if it works (I don't know and won't try), it's a stupid idea as it significantly increases the complexity of the network setup.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need a *route* to that other gateway. If you don't have *any* type of connection on that other network, then you can't. If you do, then you must add a route to your routing table.

If you want *all* traffic to use a different gateway, then you need to change your default gateway. If you only want certain traffic to use a different gateway, than you need to edit either the routing table of the workstation(s) that needs to access that other network, or the main router itself.

How to edit routing tables differ from router to router, OS to OS, so without more specifics I cannot help further, but then again if you know what type of router you have, Google is probably your best friend.